# Incoming call not triggering OnNavigateAway?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, xna-4.0

I have a WP7 XNA game that needs to save the state whenever the user navigates away. This happens when the users presses presses the Start button, Back button etc. However, the game does not pause and nothing happens when I have an incoming call (even when I take the call).

Does receiving a call not trigger OnNavigateAway ? It feels like this because you don't get the classic back-navigation transition, but it's more like an overlay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle `Obscured` event to pause a game. This event raised when some UI chrome is above the screen. Calls, Message Box, etc. This [tutorials](http://guinnesslee.wordpress.com/2011/06/26/how-to-run-your-wp7-app-even-under-lock-screen/) should help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for the Deactivated event handler. Use something like the following code where "GameDeactived" is your method of actions for when the user pressed the home button or takes a call etc.

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.Deactivated +=
                  new EventHandler<Microsoft.Phone.Shell.DeactivatedEventArgs>(GameDeactivated);
```

Hope that helps.